# MATLAB Status Bar Default Text

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to change MATLAB default 'Busy' status bar text to for example: 'My text, Busy'? So that whenever MATLAB is busy processing it displays 'My text, Busy' in the status bar. I have found a MATLAB function: [statusbar](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14773-statusbar) that can change the text.

```
statusbar(0, 'Desktop status: processing...');
```

Could someone let me know how I can make this the default?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to hook that deeply into MATLAB's engine, you may need to just call it in your processing functions.